# In bootstrap want table to be same width when displaying with/without collapsible elements

Tags: bootstrap-5

In bootstrap 5 I would like table to be displayed same width when displaying with/without collapsible elements. Currently it display shorter when not displaying the collapsible elements, which is irritating for user. Seems want it to consider collapsible elements when setting width but don't know how to do this.

Code is

```
 <div class="row justify-content-end">
    <div class="col m-2">
        <button id="show_credits_button" type="btn" class="btn btn-outline-primary m-1" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#credits_id">
            Show Credits
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2 ms-auto m-2">
        <span class="input-group">
            <span for="filter" id="filterlabel" class="input-group-text">
                Filter
            </span>
            <input type="text" id="filter" name="filter" onkeyup="filterOnly()" class="form-control">
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col m-2">
        <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                        <b>
                            Disc 1
                        </b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="song_id">
                    <td>
                        1
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <div>
                            <label class="h6">
                                Take On Me
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse" id="credits_id">
                            <div class="lh-1">
                                <label class="small figure-caption">
                                    Performed by 
                                </label>
                                <span>
                                    <a href="/artist.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=a-ha&amp;cid=0$=Artists$19126" class="small figure-caption">
                                        a-ha
                                    </a>
                                    <label class="small figure-caption">
                                         
                                    </label>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: collapsible hidden]
[image: collapsible displayed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the answer by @Cervus, you are having this issue as uncollapsing changes the width of the element which has no constraints reshifting things around, to fix this you'd want to set a forced width to the column to do this with bootstrap you can use rows and cols as shown:

https://codepen.io/rokasrudys/pen/OJvRwdQ

```html
<div class="row g-0">
<table class="table table-sm table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
        <b>
          Disc 1
        </b>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="song_id">
      <td class="col-1">1</td>
        <td class="col-8 col-sm-6 align-start">
          <label class="h6 ">
            Take On Me
          </label>
          <div class="collapse" id="credits_id">
            <div class="lh-1">
              <label class="small figure-caption">
                Performed by
              </label>
              <span>
                <a href="" class="small figure-caption">
                  a-ha
                </a>
                <label class="small figure-caption">

                </label>
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td class='col-1' >
          time
        </td>
        <td class='col-1'>
          <button>queue </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I see so you move the col from surrounding the table to columns within the table, I didn't realize you could put them between row and col. I think that is the correct solution thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

Add an id (e.g., `set_width`) and set `width: 500px !important;`.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row g-0">
    <div class="col m-2">
        <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">
                      <b>Disc 1</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="song_id">
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td id="set_width">
                        <div>
                            <label class="h6">Take On Me</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="collapse" id="credits_id">
                            <div class="lh-1">
                                <label class="small figure-caption">Performed by </label>
                                <span>
                                    <a href="/artist.start?id=70bd15b0-c1b3-4f0d-b275-c1f8553ae1f6&amp;title=a-ha&amp;cid=0$=Artists$19126" class="small figure-caption">a-ha</a>
                                    <label class="small figure-caption"></label>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#set_width {
  width: 500px !important;
}
```

Let me know if this is helpful.

Comment: You mean set a class, I dont particulary want to hard code the width I just always want bootstrap to considet the hidden data when decidding on the width, what does !important do ?

Comment: It's very, very hard to say what's the problem based on the code you've provided in the question. I need to see **exactly** what happens when you click on the "Show Credits" button. Is this website live, can you provide the link? Can you reproduce the problem with a snippet? I need to have at least a snippet where I can click on the "Show Credits" and reproduce the problem. Having screenshots isn't enough.